# Dropdown menu click-outside

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button (hamburger menu) and a dropdown menu just beneath him.
When I click on my hamburger button, I want my dropdown menu who appears. 
And when I click outside my dropdown menu I want them to disappear... logic ever since.

But my button who triggers the appearing is also outside the dropdown menu ... so if I put an event on the dropdown clickoutside, my button will never be triggered (click event + clickoutside dropdown => nothing happens)

So how can I do that?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the button a class name you haven't used yet then on the click event check the $event target and its classlist. If it has the class name you have chosen, ignore the click outside event.

If you provide some code samples, I can provide you how to do it step-by-step.

Comment: This is not an Answer. If you need more clarifications from OP on a poorly formatted question - use the comments section.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused with the question but I will go forward and answer with my understanding of the question.
So you have a hamburger icon beneath which is a menu dropdown and on click of hamburger icon you want to open the menu drop down and click other than this should close the dropdown - issue faced: Hamburger is also outside the menu drop down

You can apply a check on the event.target whether it disobeys presence of a particular class that both your dropdown and hamburger hold, so whenever a click is made on the document if the event.target doesn't hold the class present on the element then close the dropdown by applying the collapsible class.

**Note:**

***".menu-element"*** is the class applied to your hamburger element as well as the menu dropdown element.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
     if (!$(e.target).is('.menu-element')) {
         $('.collapse').collapse('hide');     
        }
    });
```